# How to use FIND_IN_SET in jpa

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0, find-in-set

How can I use `find_in_set` in jpa?

I need to achieve like this
**SQL -** `select * from teacher where find_in_set("5", deptIds) and id = 101`

where `deptIds` have comma separated ids (I know it's bad idea but legacy.)

To do so I had been tried using `Criteria` but not found any `Restrictions` that can fulfill `find_in_set`.
**Note** - need possible solution with `Criteria` and `Restrictions`

Answer (score 0):

```
criteriaBuilder.function("find_in_set", Boolean.class,
        criteriaBuilder.literal(s),
        root.get("field"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is [an example](https://github.com/aborn/mindpress-serv/blob/27fb832f6eeec0241d35648751414ff7a9219763/src/main/java/com/github/aborn/mindpress/inf/utils/QueryHelp.java):
[image: find_in_set example]

Here is java code snippet.

```java
    list.add(cb.greaterThan(cb.function("FIND_IN_SET", Integer.class,
                                    cb.literal(val.toString()), root.get(attributeName)), 0));
```

Answer (score -2):

```sql
select t from Teacher t where find_in_set("5", t.deptIds) = 0 and t.id = 101
```

Comment: LMAO. You can't be serious right?